# How to delete a specific node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list, delete-operator

I have the next linked list code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define null 0

class Node
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    Node *next;
    Node(string name, int age)
    {
        this->age = age;
        this->name = name;
        this->next = null;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        this->head = null;
    }

    void insert(string name, int age)
    {
        Node *nodenew = new Node(name, age);
        nodenew->next = null;
        if (this->head == null)
        {
            this->head = nodenew;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *temp = this->head;
            while (temp->next != null)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = nodenew;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        if (this->head == null)
        {
            cout << "Empty";
        }

        Node *temp = this->head;

        while (temp != null)
        {
            cout << temp->name << ", " << temp->age <<endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void deletePerson(string name){
        Node *temp = this->head;
        Node* prev = null;

        if (temp!=null && temp->name == name)
        {
            this->head = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return;
        }else
        {
            while (temp != null && temp->name == name)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;     
        } 
    }


};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    LinkedList list;
    list.insert("David", 45);
    list.insert("John", 23);
    list.insert("Katty", 78);
    list.insert("Stephanie", 25);
    list.deletePerson("Katty");
    list.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to delete a node by a given name with the next method:

```
void deletePerson(string name){
        Node *temp = this->head;
        Node* prev = null;

        if (temp!=null && temp->name == name)
        {
            this->head = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return;
        }else
        {
            while (temp != null && temp->name == name)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;     
        } 
    }
```

But when I compile my code it doesn´t show me anything in console, it just show the next code error:

```
code=3221225477
```

I tried to debugger my code but vscode just swap me to other class, in `prev->next = temp->next;` part it just show a little message that says:

```
Exception has occurred. X
Segmentation fault
```

My expected output would be:

```
David, 45
John, 23
Stephanie, 25
```

I hope you can help me to solve that, thanks.

Comment: This page will decode the message: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225477](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=3221225477)

Comment: Which C++ textbook you're using to learn C++, that's teaching you to write Java instead of C++? Does your C++ textbook explain how to use member initialization syntax in constructors, instead of the awkward `this->` syntax, and also use the same awkward syntax even where it is not needed at all?

Comment: `while (temp != null && temp->name == name)` will not advance if the head is not the item you are searching so in that case you have `prev->next = temp->next;` when `prev` is a null pointer. Are you sure you wanted to loop while `temp->name == name` ?

Comment: Your `insert` method should be named `append`. BTW you can avoid all this special case code to handle the head element by using pointer to pointer to node instead of pointer to node.

Comment: There's a lot to not like about that Node class. Like how it's a Person and a Node at the same time.

Comment: FYI, if you use a coding style where member names are different than parameter names, you don't need to use the `this->` syntax.  One example is to prefix member names with "m_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is so simple, it's in that line:

```
while (temp != null && temp->name == name)
```

it should be:

```
while (temp != null && temp->name != name)
```

as the condition of looping, you are looping until you either didn't reach the end (`temp != null`) or the name isn't found in this iteration (`temp->name != name`).

also, there is a small warning at this line:

```
prev->next = temp->next;
```

imagine if you didn't find the node, then `temp` will be null, and the line `temp->next;` will throw an error as you are trying to dereference a null pointer.

I know you handled this situation in your code as you wrote:

```
if (temp == null)
{
     return;
}
```

but for safety reasons or in case your compiler complained about it as mine, you should check if both `prev` and `temp` are  null pointers or not, so it should be:

```
if(null !=  prev && null != temp)
     prev->next = temp->next;
```

after this edited, this is the output:

```
David, 45
John, 23
Stephanie, 25
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I need to replace `prev->next = temp->next;
` with `if(null !=  prev && null != temp) prev->next = temp->next;` ?

Comment: @riram, no, you don't need to but you should in case your compiler complains about this line, as my compiler complained about this line as there is a possibility of dereferencing a null pointer